# Encoding Text to Base64 and decoding back to JSON

Tags: node.js, json, express, base64

I am trying to encode a text to Base64 and using NodeJS, and then while getting the data I am decoding it back from Base64. Now I need to change the data into JSON so I could fill the relevant fields but its not converting to JSON.

Here is my code:

```
fs.readFile('./setting.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var encodedData = base64.encode(data);

    var decoded = base64.decode(encodedData).replace(/\n/g, '').replace(/\s/g, " ");
    
   return res.status(200).send(decoded);

    });
```

In **setting.txt** I have the following text:

```
LENGTH=1076
CRC16=28653
OFFSET=37
MEASUREMENT_SAMPLING_RATE=4
MEASUREMENT_RANGE=1
MEASUREMENT_TRACE_LENGTH=16384
MEASUREMENT_PRETRIGGER_LENGTH=0
MEASUREMENT_UNIT=2
MEASUREMENT_OFFSET_REMOVER=1
```

This decodes the result properly but when I use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(decoded )` its not converting to JSON.

Can someone help me with it.

Comment: How is your problem related to Base64 encoding/decoding? You wrote *This decodes the result properly*, so it's not relevant at all, right?! Please don't mention things that are not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try below snippet

```
let base64Json=  new Buffer(JSON.stringify({}),"base64").toString('base64');
let json = new Buffer(base64Json, 'ascii').toString('ascii');
```

Comment: I tried this but its giving error:
`var encodedData = base64.encode(data);

let base64Json=  new Buffer.alloc(JSON.stringify(decoded),"base64").toString('base64');
let json = new Buffer.alloc(base64Json, 'ascii').toString('ascii');`

Comment: Can you please share a sample JSON?. That I can fix and share a working version. Thanks

Comment: Check the text mentioned in the **setting.txt** I want to first encode it to Base64 and then back to the same text which is already been done...Now I want the converted values converted to JSON to get specific values.

Comment: Please first build a proper JSON object to encode in base64 then decode it as the way I wrote above. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What does base-64 encoding/decoding have to do with mapping a list of tuples (key/value pairs) like this:

```
LENGTH=1076
CRC16=28653
OFFSET=37
MEASUREMENT_SAMPLING_RATE=4
MEASUREMENT_RANGE=1
MEASUREMENT_TRACE_LENGTH=16384
MEASUREMENT_PRETRIGGER_LENGTH=0
MEASUREMENT_UNIT=2
MEASUREMENT_OFFSET_REMOVER=1
```

into JSON?

If you want to "turn it (the above) into JSON", you need to:

- Decide on what its JSON representation should be, then
- Parse it into its component bits, convert that into an appropriate data struct, and then
- use `JSON.stringify()` to convert it to JSON.

For instance:

```
function jsonify( document ) {
  const tuples = document
                 .split( /\n|\r\n?/ )
                 .map( x => x.split( '=', 2) )
                 .map( ([k,v]) => {
                   const n = Number(n);
                   return [ k , n === NaN ? v : n ];
                 });
  const obj = Object.fromEntries(tuples);

  const json = JSON.stringify(obj);
  return json;
}
```